# Get distinct values from two different parts of an XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have had a business rule change to one of my XSLTs and I am not sure how to handle it. If you look at the XML below, you will see that I have an employee section and an equipment section. The employee section has a WorkOrderNumber nested in a day tag and a TimeDetail tag and there is an EquipmentWorkOrderNumber nested in the Equipment -> EquipmentWorkOrder.

I use to just need to get the distinct WorkOrderNumber because there would be a correlation between WorkOrderNumber and EquipmentWorkOrderNumber but now, there may be additional EquipmentWorkOrderNumber that aren’t present in the employee WorkOrderNumber section.

I need to get distinct WorkOrderNumber and EquipmentWorkOrderNumber without duplicating the values. I have tried many, many variations of the code below with no real progress.

```
<!-- The Key at the top --> 
<xsl:key name="distinctWoEquipWo" match="//WorkOrderNumber | //EquipmentWorkOrderNumber" use="."/>

<!-- Where I loop through the distinct values -->
<xsl:for-each select=".//WorkOrderNumber | .//EquipmentWorkOrderNumber[generate-id() = generate-id(key('distinctWoEquipWo', .)[1])]">
```

Is it possible to get distinct WorkOrderNumber and EquipmentWorkOrderNumber values in a select?

Here is the XML that I am working with?

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="TemplateTest.xsl"?>
<Timesheet>
<WeekEnding>Apr 28, 2013</WeekEnding>
<TeamMember>
    <EmployeeNumber>AB00910</EmployeeNumber>
    <EmployeeName>Demo, Derek</EmployeeName>
    <EmployeeClass>F</EmployeeClass>
    <Monday>
        <TimeDetail>
            <StartTime>Start</StartTime>
            <StopTime>Stop</StopTime>
            <WorkOrderNumber>4812537</WorkOrderNumber>
            <RegularHoursStartTime>Start</RegularHoursStartTime>
            <RegularHoursStopTime>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime>
            <RegularHoursStartTime2>Start</RegularHoursStartTime2>
            <RegularHoursStopTime2>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime2>
            <RegularHours>9</RegularHours>
            <OverTimeStartTime>Start</OverTimeStartTime>
            <OverTimeStopTime>Stop</OverTimeStopTime>
            <OverTimeStartTime2>Start</OverTimeStartTime2>
            <OverTimeStopTime2>Stop</OverTimeStopTime2>
            <OverTimeHours>Over Time</OverTimeHours>
            <OtherStartTime>Start</OtherStartTime>
            <OtherStopTime>Stop</OtherStopTime>
            <OtherStartTime2>Start</OtherStartTime2>
            <OtherStopTime2>Stop</OtherStopTime2>
            <OtherHours>Other</OtherHours>
            <PerDiem>NO</PerDiem>
            <Notes>Notes</Notes>
        </TimeDetail>
    </Monday>
    <Tuesday>
        <TimeDetail>
            <StartTime>Start</StartTime>
            <StopTime>Stop</StopTime>
            <WorkOrderNumber>4812537</WorkOrderNumber>
            <RegularHoursStartTime>Start</RegularHoursStartTime>
            <RegularHoursStopTime>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime>
            <RegularHoursStartTime2>Start</RegularHoursStartTime2>
            <RegularHoursStopTime2>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime2>
            <RegularHours>12</RegularHours>
            <OverTimeStartTime>Start</OverTimeStartTime>
            <OverTimeStopTime>Stop</OverTimeStopTime>
            <OverTimeStartTime2>Start</OverTimeStartTime2>
            <OverTimeStopTime2>Stop</OverTimeStopTime2>
            <OverTimeHours>Over Time</OverTimeHours>
            <OtherStartTime>Start</OtherStartTime>
            <OtherStopTime>Stop</OtherStopTime>
            <OtherStartTime2>Start</OtherStartTime2>
            <OtherStopTime2>Stop</OtherStopTime2>
            <OtherHours>Other</OtherHours>
            <PerDiem>NO</PerDiem>
            <Notes>Notes</Notes>
        </TimeDetail>
    </Tuesday>
    <Wednesday>
        <TimeDetail>
            <StartTime>Start</StartTime>
            <StopTime>Stop</StopTime>
            <WorkOrderNumber>4812537</WorkOrderNumber>
            <RegularHoursStartTime>Start</RegularHoursStartTime>
            <RegularHoursStopTime>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime>
            <RegularHoursStartTime2>Start</RegularHoursStartTime2>
            <RegularHoursStopTime2>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime2>
            <RegularHours>11</RegularHours>
            <OverTimeStartTime>Start</OverTimeStartTime>
            <OverTimeStopTime>Stop</OverTimeStopTime>
            <OverTimeStartTime2>Start</OverTimeStartTime2>
            <OverTimeStopTime2>Stop</OverTimeStopTime2>
            <OverTimeHours>Over Time</OverTimeHours>
            <OtherStartTime>Start</OtherStartTime>
            <OtherStopTime>Stop</OtherStopTime>
            <OtherStartTime2>Start</OtherStartTime2>
            <OtherStopTime2>Stop</OtherStopTime2>
            <OtherHours>Other</OtherHours>
            <PerDiem>NO</PerDiem>
            <Notes>Notes</Notes>
        </TimeDetail>
    </Wednesday>
    <Thursday>
        <TimeDetail>
            <StartTime>Start</StartTime>
            <StopTime>Stop</StopTime>
            <WorkOrderNumber>4812537</WorkOrderNumber>
            <RegularHoursStartTime>Start</RegularHoursStartTime>
            <RegularHoursStopTime>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime>
            <RegularHoursStartTime2>Start</RegularHoursStartTime2>
            <RegularHoursStopTime2>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime2>
            <RegularHours>8</RegularHours>
            <OverTimeStartTime>Start</OverTimeStartTime>
            <OverTimeStopTime>Stop</OverTimeStopTime>
            <OverTimeStartTime2>Start</OverTimeStartTime2>
            <OverTimeStopTime2>Stop</OverTimeStopTime2>
            <OverTimeHours>3</OverTimeHours>
            <OtherStartTime>Start</OtherStartTime>
            <OtherStopTime>Stop</OtherStopTime>
            <OtherStartTime2>Start</OtherStartTime2>
            <OtherStopTime2>Stop</OtherStopTime2>
            <OtherHours>Other</OtherHours>
            <PerDiem>NO</PerDiem>
            <Notes>Notes</Notes>
        </TimeDetail>
    </Thursday>
    <Friday>
        <TimeDetail>
            <StartTime>Start</StartTime>
            <StopTime>Stop</StopTime>
            <WorkOrderNumber>4812537</WorkOrderNumber>
            <RegularHoursStartTime>Start</RegularHoursStartTime>
            <RegularHoursStopTime>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime>
            <RegularHoursStartTime2>Start</RegularHoursStartTime2>
            <RegularHoursStopTime2>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime2>
            <RegularHours>0</RegularHours>
            <OverTimeStartTime>Start</OverTimeStartTime>
            <OverTimeStopTime>Stop</OverTimeStopTime>
            <OverTimeStartTime2>Start</OverTimeStartTime2>
            <OverTimeStopTime2>Stop</OverTimeStopTime2>
            <OverTimeHours>7</OverTimeHours>
            <OtherStartTime>Start</OtherStartTime>
            <OtherStopTime>Stop</OtherStopTime>
            <OtherStartTime2>Start</OtherStartTime2>
            <OtherStopTime2>Stop</OtherStopTime2>
            <OtherHours>Other</OtherHours>
            <PerDiem>NO</PerDiem>
            <Notes>Notes</Notes>
        </TimeDetail>
    </Friday>
    <Saturday />
    <Sunday />
    <CrewLeader>1</CrewLeader>
</TeamMember>
<TeamMember>
    <EmployeeNumber>BB7789A</EmployeeNumber>
    <EmployeeName>Employee, Daniel</EmployeeName>
    <EmployeeClass>AL</EmployeeClass>
    <Monday />
    <Tuesday>
        <TimeDetail>
            <StartTime>Start</StartTime>
            <StopTime>Stop</StopTime>
            <WorkOrderNumber>4812537</WorkOrderNumber>
            <RegularHoursStartTime>Start</RegularHoursStartTime>
            <RegularHoursStopTime>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime>
            <RegularHoursStartTime2>Start</RegularHoursStartTime2>
            <RegularHoursStopTime2>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime2>
            <RegularHours>12</RegularHours>
            <OverTimeStartTime>Start</OverTimeStartTime>
            <OverTimeStopTime>Stop</OverTimeStopTime>
            <OverTimeStartTime2>Start</OverTimeStartTime2>
            <OverTimeStopTime2>Stop</OverTimeStopTime2>
            <OverTimeHours>Over Time</OverTimeHours>
            <OtherStartTime>Start</OtherStartTime>
            <OtherStopTime>Stop</OtherStopTime>
            <OtherStartTime2>Start</OtherStartTime2>
            <OtherStopTime2>Stop</OtherStopTime2>
            <OtherHours>Other</OtherHours>
            <PerDiem>YES</PerDiem>
            <Notes>5xfullperdiem</Notes>
        </TimeDetail>
    </Tuesday>
    <Wednesday>
        <TimeDetail>
            <StartTime>Start</StartTime>
            <StopTime>Stop</StopTime>
            <WorkOrderNumber>4812537</WorkOrderNumber>
            <RegularHoursStartTime>Start</RegularHoursStartTime>
            <RegularHoursStopTime>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime>
            <RegularHoursStartTime2>Start</RegularHoursStartTime2>
            <RegularHoursStopTime2>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime2>
            <RegularHours>11</RegularHours>
            <OverTimeStartTime>Start</OverTimeStartTime>
            <OverTimeStopTime>Stop</OverTimeStopTime>
            <OverTimeStartTime2>Start</OverTimeStartTime2>
            <OverTimeStopTime2>Stop</OverTimeStopTime2>
            <OverTimeHours>Over Time</OverTimeHours>
            <OtherStartTime>Start</OtherStartTime>
            <OtherStopTime>Stop</OtherStopTime>
            <OtherStartTime2>Start</OtherStartTime2>
            <OtherStopTime2>Stop</OtherStopTime2>
            <OtherHours>Other</OtherHours>
            <PerDiem>YES</PerDiem>
            <Notes>5xfullperdiem</Notes>
        </TimeDetail>
    </Wednesday>
    <Thursday>
        <TimeDetail>
            <StartTime>Start</StartTime>
            <StopTime>Stop</StopTime>
            <WorkOrderNumber>4812537</WorkOrderNumber>
            <RegularHoursStartTime>Start</RegularHoursStartTime>
            <RegularHoursStopTime>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime>
            <RegularHoursStartTime2>Start</RegularHoursStartTime2>
            <RegularHoursStopTime2>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime2>
            <RegularHours>8</RegularHours>
            <OverTimeStartTime>Start</OverTimeStartTime>
            <OverTimeStopTime>Stop</OverTimeStopTime>
            <OverTimeStartTime2>Start</OverTimeStartTime2>
            <OverTimeStopTime2>Stop</OverTimeStopTime2>
            <OverTimeHours>3</OverTimeHours>
            <OtherStartTime>Start</OtherStartTime>
            <OtherStopTime>Stop</OtherStopTime>
            <OtherStartTime2>Start</OtherStartTime2>
            <OtherStopTime2>Stop</OtherStopTime2>
            <OtherHours>Other</OtherHours>
            <PerDiem>YES</PerDiem>
            <Notes>5xfullperdiem</Notes>
        </TimeDetail>
    </Thursday>
    <Friday>
        <TimeDetail>
            <StartTime>Start</StartTime>
            <StopTime>Stop</StopTime>
            <WorkOrderNumber>4812537</WorkOrderNumber>
            <RegularHoursStartTime>Start</RegularHoursStartTime>
            <RegularHoursStopTime>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime>
            <RegularHoursStartTime2>Start</RegularHoursStartTime2>
            <RegularHoursStopTime2>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime2>
            <RegularHours>Regular</RegularHours>
            <OverTimeStartTime>Start</OverTimeStartTime>
            <OverTimeStopTime>Stop</OverTimeStopTime>
            <OverTimeStartTime2>Start</OverTimeStartTime2>
            <OverTimeStopTime2>Stop</OverTimeStopTime2>
            <OverTimeHours>7</OverTimeHours>
            <OtherStartTime>Start</OtherStartTime>
            <OtherStopTime>Stop</OtherStopTime>
            <OtherStartTime2>Start</OtherStartTime2>
            <OtherStopTime2>Stop</OtherStopTime2>
            <OtherHours>Other</OtherHours>
            <PerDiem>YES</PerDiem>
            <Notes>5xfullperdiem</Notes>
        </TimeDetail>
    </Friday>
    <Saturday />
    <Sunday />
</TeamMember>
<TeamMember>
    <EmployeeNumber>CDE890</EmployeeNumber>
    <EmployeeName>Test, John</EmployeeName>
    <EmployeeClass>G</EmployeeClass>
    <Monday>
        <TimeDetail>
            <StartTime>Start</StartTime>
            <StopTime>Stop</StopTime>
            <WorkOrderNumber>4812537</WorkOrderNumber>
            <RegularHoursStartTime>Start</RegularHoursStartTime>
            <RegularHoursStopTime>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime>
            <RegularHoursStartTime2>Start</RegularHoursStartTime2>
            <RegularHoursStopTime2>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime2>
            <RegularHours>9</RegularHours>
            <OverTimeStartTime>Start</OverTimeStartTime>
            <OverTimeStopTime>Stop</OverTimeStopTime>
            <OverTimeStartTime2>Start</OverTimeStartTime2>
            <OverTimeStopTime2>Stop</OverTimeStopTime2>
            <OverTimeHours>Over Time</OverTimeHours>
            <OtherStartTime>Start</OtherStartTime>
            <OtherStopTime>Stop</OtherStopTime>
            <OtherStartTime2>Start</OtherStartTime2>
            <OtherStopTime2>Stop</OtherStopTime2>
            <OtherHours>Other</OtherHours>
            <PerDiem>NO</PerDiem>
            <Notes>Notes</Notes>
        </TimeDetail>
    </Monday>
    <Tuesday>
        <TimeDetail>
            <StartTime>Start</StartTime>
            <StopTime>Stop</StopTime>
            <WorkOrderNumber>4812537</WorkOrderNumber>
            <RegularHoursStartTime>Start</RegularHoursStartTime>
            <RegularHoursStopTime>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime>
            <RegularHoursStartTime2>Start</RegularHoursStartTime2>
            <RegularHoursStopTime2>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime2>
            <RegularHours>12</RegularHours>
            <OverTimeStartTime>Start</OverTimeStartTime>
            <OverTimeStopTime>Stop</OverTimeStopTime>
            <OverTimeStartTime2>Start</OverTimeStartTime2>
            <OverTimeStopTime2>Stop</OverTimeStopTime2>
            <OverTimeHours>Over Time</OverTimeHours>
            <OtherStartTime>Start</OtherStartTime>
            <OtherStopTime>Stop</OtherStopTime>
            <OtherStartTime2>Start</OtherStartTime2>
            <OtherStopTime2>Stop</OtherStopTime2>
            <OtherHours>Other</OtherHours>
            <PerDiem>NO</PerDiem>
            <Notes>Notes</Notes>
        </TimeDetail>
    </Tuesday>
    <Wednesday>
        <TimeDetail>
            <StartTime>Start</StartTime>
            <StopTime>Stop</StopTime>
            <WorkOrderNumber>4812537</WorkOrderNumber>
            <RegularHoursStartTime>Start</RegularHoursStartTime>
            <RegularHoursStopTime>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime>
            <RegularHoursStartTime2>Start</RegularHoursStartTime2>
            <RegularHoursStopTime2>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime2>
            <RegularHours>11</RegularHours>
            <OverTimeStartTime>Start</OverTimeStartTime>
            <OverTimeStopTime>Stop</OverTimeStopTime>
            <OverTimeStartTime2>Start</OverTimeStartTime2>
            <OverTimeStopTime2>Stop</OverTimeStopTime2>
            <OverTimeHours>Over Time</OverTimeHours>
            <OtherStartTime>Start</OtherStartTime>
            <OtherStopTime>Stop</OtherStopTime>
            <OtherStartTime2>Start</OtherStartTime2>
            <OtherStopTime2>Stop</OtherStopTime2>
            <OtherHours>Other</OtherHours>
            <PerDiem>NO</PerDiem>
            <Notes>Notes</Notes>
        </TimeDetail>
    </Wednesday>
    <Thursday>
        <TimeDetail>
            <StartTime>Start</StartTime>
            <StopTime>Stop</StopTime>
            <WorkOrderNumber>4812537</WorkOrderNumber>
            <RegularHoursStartTime>Start</RegularHoursStartTime>
            <RegularHoursStopTime>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime>
            <RegularHoursStartTime2>Start</RegularHoursStartTime2>
            <RegularHoursStopTime2>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime2>
            <RegularHours>8</RegularHours>
            <OverTimeStartTime>Start</OverTimeStartTime>
            <OverTimeStopTime>Stop</OverTimeStopTime>
            <OverTimeStartTime2>Start</OverTimeStartTime2>
            <OverTimeStopTime2>Stop</OverTimeStopTime2>
            <OverTimeHours>3</OverTimeHours>
            <OtherStartTime>Start</OtherStartTime>
            <OtherStopTime>Stop</OtherStopTime>
            <OtherStartTime2>Start</OtherStartTime2>
            <OtherStopTime2>Stop</OtherStopTime2>
            <OtherHours>Other</OtherHours>
            <PerDiem>NO</PerDiem>
            <Notes>Notes</Notes>
        </TimeDetail>
    </Thursday>
    <Friday>
        <TimeDetail>
            <StartTime>Start</StartTime>
            <StopTime>Stop</StopTime>
            <WorkOrderNumber>4812537</WorkOrderNumber>
            <RegularHoursStartTime>Start</RegularHoursStartTime>
            <RegularHoursStopTime>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime>
            <RegularHoursStartTime2>Start</RegularHoursStartTime2>
            <RegularHoursStopTime2>Stop</RegularHoursStopTime2>
            <RegularHours>0</RegularHours>
            <OverTimeStartTime>Start</OverTimeStartTime>
            <OverTimeStopTime>Stop</OverTimeStopTime>
            <OverTimeStartTime2>Start</OverTimeStartTime2>
            <OverTimeStopTime2>Stop</OverTimeStopTime2>
            <OverTimeHours>7</OverTimeHours>
            <OtherStartTime>Start</OtherStartTime>
            <OtherStopTime>Stop</OtherStopTime>
            <OtherStartTime2>Start</OtherStartTime2>
            <OtherStopTime2>Stop</OtherStopTime2>
            <OtherHours>Other</OtherHours>
            <PerDiem>NO</PerDiem>
            <Notes>Notes</Notes>
        </TimeDetail>
    </Friday>
    <Saturday />
    <Sunday />
</TeamMember>
<Equipment>
    <EquipmentWorkOrder>
        <EquipmentWorkOrderNumber>4812537</EquipmentWorkOrderNumber>
        <EquipmentDetail>
            <EquipmentMileage>Mileage</EquipmentMileage>
            <EquipmentHourMeter>Hour Meter</EquipmentHourMeter>
            <EquipmentType>Bucket truck</EquipmentType>
            <EquipmentNumber>8s96</EquipmentNumber>
            <MondayHours>0</MondayHours>
            <TuesdayHours>12</TuesdayHours>
            <WednesdayHours>11</WednesdayHours>
            <ThursdayHours>11</ThursdayHours>
            <FridayHours>7</FridayHours>
            <SaturdayHours>Saturday</SaturdayHours>
            <SundayHours>Sunday</SundayHours>
            <EquipmentNotes>Notes</EquipmentNotes>
        </EquipmentDetail>
        <EquipmentDetail>
            <EquipmentMileage>Mileage</EquipmentMileage>
            <EquipmentHourMeter>Hour Meter</EquipmentHourMeter>
            <EquipmentType>Line truck</EquipmentType>
            <EquipmentNumber>20x949</EquipmentNumber>
            <MondayHours>9</MondayHours>
            <TuesdayHours>12</TuesdayHours>
            <WednesdayHours>11</WednesdayHours>
            <ThursdayHours>11</ThursdayHours>
            <FridayHours>7</FridayHours>
            <SaturdayHours>Saturday</SaturdayHours>
            <SundayHours>Sunday</SundayHours>
            <EquipmentNotes>Notes</EquipmentNotes>
        </EquipmentDetail>
        <EquipmentDetail>
            <EquipmentMileage>Mileage</EquipmentMileage>
            <EquipmentHourMeter>Hour Meter</EquipmentHourMeter>
            <EquipmentType>Pickup truck</EquipmentType>
            <EquipmentNumber>38g356</EquipmentNumber>
            <MondayHours>9</MondayHours>
            <TuesdayHours>12</TuesdayHours>
            <WednesdayHours>11</WednesdayHours>
            <ThursdayHours>11</ThursdayHours>
            <FridayHours>7</FridayHours>
            <SaturdayHours>Saturday</SaturdayHours>
            <SundayHours>Sunday</SundayHours>
            <EquipmentNotes>Notes</EquipmentNotes>
        </EquipmentDetail>
        <EquipmentDetail>
            <EquipmentMileage>Mileage</EquipmentMileage>
            <EquipmentHourMeter>Hour Meter</EquipmentHourMeter>
            <EquipmentType>Air compressor</EquipmentType>
            <EquipmentNumber>1d158</EquipmentNumber>
            <MondayHours>9</MondayHours>
            <TuesdayHours>12</TuesdayHours>
            <WednesdayHours>11</WednesdayHours>
            <ThursdayHours>11</ThursdayHours>
            <FridayHours>7</FridayHours>
            <SaturdayHours>Saturday</SaturdayHours>
            <SundayHours>Sunday</SundayHours>
            <EquipmentNotes>Notes</EquipmentNotes>
        </EquipmentDetail>
    </EquipmentWorkOrder>
</Equipment>
</Timesheet>
```

Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: Could you show us the XML output you expect to receive?

Comment: The output is html and there is a lot of it but in the loop above I am trying to print the heading with the work order numbers as so. <xsl:for-each select=".//WorkOrderNumber | .//EquipmentWorkOrderNumber[generate-id() = generate-id(key('distinctWoEquipWo', .)[1])]"><td colspan="4" class="woNums">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </td>
                  <td colspan="4" class="woNumsFill">&#160;</td>
                  <td></td></xsl:for-each>

Comment: @inosu812 seems to work for me (wiht xsltoroc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was you needed parentheses around the node selection for inclusion in your key, like this `(//WorkOrderNumber | //EquipmentWorkOrderNumber)[generate-id...`. Otherwise you are simply looping over the `WorkOrderNumber` nodes and only including `EquipmentWorkOrderNumber` in the key and looping over those too.

More fully...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="workOrderNumberDistinct" match="WorkOrderNumber | EquipmentWorkOrderNumber" use="text()"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <DistinctWorkOrderNumbers>
      <xsl:for-each select="(//WorkOrderNumber | //EquipmentWorkOrderNumber)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('workOrderNumberDistinct', text())[1])]">
        <Number>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Number>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </DistinctWorkOrderNumbers>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Outputs...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DistinctWorkOrderNumbers>
  <Number>4812537</Number>
</DistinctWorkOrderNumbers>
```

Comment: If you copy the data for Monday to Saturday you will see that it brings in the work order number two times. I will see if I can get some other XML data to demonstrate that.

Comment: Ah OK, I have altered the input XML myself and see what you mean. My transformation above still works though. You need the brackets around this `(//WorkOrderNumber | //EquipmentWorkOrderNumber)`.

Comment: Ok. I also changed the XML data above so that everyone can get a more complete view of what I am talking about.

Comment: Strange the way we can't see `</Timesheet>` in your new input XML above. But if you go into edit, it is there!

Comment: I fixed it. I needed to put 4 spaces in front of it so that it would be recognized as code.

Comment: My transformation still seems to work. Added more info above. Let me know if there is still an issue.

Comment: It looks like it works on both sets of data. Thanks a lot. I have been trying different things for 2 and a half days and you did it in a few minutes. That's awesome. Thanks.

Comment: No probs at all. It took longer than a few mins though ;)